# Define the binary operation $\bigtriangleup$ on $P(A)$ by $X \triangle Y = (X-Y) \cup (Y-X)$.Prove $\langle P(A), \triangle\rangle$ is group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations, associativity

> Let A be a set.Define the binary operation $\bigtriangleup$ on $P(A)$
>   by $X \bigtriangleup Y = (X-Y) \cup (Y-X)$ for all $X,Y \in
>  P(A)$.Prove that $\langle P(A), \bigtriangleup\rangle$ is an abelian group.

In this question I stuck in showing that the binary operator $\bigtriangleup$ is associative.

I wrote what are $X \bigtriangleup (Y \bigtriangleup Z)$ and $(X \bigtriangleup Y) \bigtriangleup Z$, and then by drawing Venn diagrams, I concluded that these two operations gives different results.I checked my calculations, but couldn't find anything.

I can write here my calculations, but the way that I have tried to solve is pretty tedious way to prove such kind of thing, so I am asking that **how can I prove that this binary operator is, in fact, associative ?**

Comment: @Surb, yes you are right, thanks, I corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1_{A \Delta B} = (1_A + 1_B) \mod 2$. Now,
$$1_{(A \Delta B) \Delta C} = (1_{A \Delta B} + 1_C) \mod 2 = (1_A + 1_B + 1_C) \mod 2$$
From the symmetry, it follows that $(A \Delta B) \Delta C = A \Delta (B \Delta C)$

Comment: what is $1_A$ ?

Comment: @Leth $1_A(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \in A \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to prove that this operator is associative is probably to note that $\triangle$ is commutative, and to prove that $x \in X \triangle (Y \triangle Z)$ if and only if it lies in all three of $X,Y,Z$ or it lies in precisely one of $X,Y,Z$. It follows that the same is true for the statement $x \in Z \triangle (X \triangle Y) = (X \triangle Y) \triangle Z$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but I need a rigorous mathematical proof, since I'm still a student.

Comment: The implicit suggestion is that you write the actual rigorous proof based on the sketch I gave.

Comment: I'm not sure that if it is the *easiest way* but it is definitely a valid way.

Answer (score 1):

Note that: $$1_{A\triangle B}=1_A+1_B-2.1_{A}1_{B}$$

Now work out $1_{X\triangle(Y\triangle Z)}$ and $1_{(X\triangle Y)\triangle Z}$ and observe that the outcomes are the same.